# Newman: html report not being generated

Tags: azure, postman, newman

I am trying to generate an HTML report for Postman scripts using Newman.

However, I don't see a report generated in the desired location.

I am using azure DevOps.

```
[command]/usr/local/bin/newman run /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/postman_collection.json --reporter-html-template /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/newman-reporter.html --reporter-html-export /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman -r cli,html -n 1 -e /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/postman_environment.json
```

I have already installed Newman and HTML report generator on the same level as far as directory is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to specify a filename extension (`.html`) rather than just the directory path.

As a fallback, it might have created the default file in a directory called `newman` at the same location that the command was run.

If you required a different HTML reporter - [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra) can be used.

Comment: I have tried using extension .html, but didn't work ask well. Updated command is:               `/usr/local/bin/newman run /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/postman_collection.json --reporter-html-template /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/newman-reporter.html --reporter-html-export /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/report.html -r cli,html -n 1 -e /home/vsts/work/1/s/Postman/postman_environment.json`

Comment: What are you seeing, just the CLI output?

Comment: Have you tried removing the template and export flags to let it pick up the defaults?

Comment: yes, cli just heads to cli reporter and no mention of html reporter.

Comment: and this didn't create the `newman` folder in the location that you ran the command

Comment: It did create a newman folder, which has the path `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman`, but there is no html file in that